# Flutter: how to hide the appbar of previous screen, when navigating to next screen from bottom navigation tab

Tags: flutter, screen, bottomnavigationview, android-appbarlayout

i want to hide/change the appbar title when i navigate to next screen on click tab from bottom navigation.

here is my code of bottom navigation

```
class Employee extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blue
      ),
      home: EmployeeNavigation(),
    );
  }
}
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  
  final _pageOptions = [
    EmployeeDashboard(),
    RequestForLeave(),
    MyAttendance(),
    Profile()
  ];
class EmployeeNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return EmployeeNavigationState();
  }
}
class EmployeeNavigationState extends State<EmployeeNavigation> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new MyAppBar(title: Text("Home"),onpressed: (){
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile()));
   }),
    drawer:Emp_DrawerCode(),
    body:  _pageOptions[_selectedTab], 
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    currentIndex: _selectedTab,
    onTap: (value) {
      print(value);
      setState(() {
        _selectedTab = value;
      });
    },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.time_to_leave), label: "Leave"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.history), label: "Attendance"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 14,
          backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/user_2.png"),
        ),
        label: "Profile",
      ),
    ],
  ));
}
}
```

when i click on leave tab then leave screen is displaying but it is also displaying home screen appbar

here is output snap
[image]

and this is widget i call on leave screen

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        drawer: drawer(),
        appBar: new MyAppBar(
          title: Text("Request for leave"),
          onpressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()));
          },
        ),
```

please help where i am doing wrong

Comment: You need to change title on page change and avoid using appbar in children widgets !

Comment: how to do that, any help with code please?

Comment: Remove appbar widget from EmployeeNavigationState class, and it's done.

Comment: @RajniGujarati it works, thanks for that, but when i navigate to leave screen drawer take few seconds to display! any suggestion to fix that?